# Why does normalizing one dimension of the input give different accuracy?

Tags: neural-network

Below is my Neural Network code that I adapted from the YouTube series by Stephen Welch. I am wondering why when I change the value of all my X's, (normalize it) it seems to produce different results. When it's X/10 there is a +90% prediction accuracy, but when I do X/4000 for example (highest value of X is 3695) I only get an accuracy of ~80%. This doesn't make sense to me since changing all of X by a set value is like changing the units. It shouldn't have an effect on the output property at all.

Where does this significant difference arise? I don't fully grasp the concepts behind the math.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from scipy import optimize
import random
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

X = np.loadtxt('xdata.txt', dtype=float)
y = np.loadtxt('ydata.txt', dtype=float)
y = np.reshape(y, (148,1))

X = X/10
y = y/5

Lambda = 0.0003

class Neural_Network(object):
    def __init__(self, Lambda = 0):        
        #Define Hyperparameters
        self.inputLayerSize = 17
        self.outputLayerSize = 1
        self.hiddenLayerSize = 17

        #Weights (parameters)
        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputLayerSize,self.hiddenLayerSize)
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenLayerSize,self.outputLayerSize)

        self.Lambda = Lambda

    def forward(self, X):
        #Propogate inputs though network
        self.z2 = np.dot(X, self.W1)
        self.a2 = self.sigmoid(self.z2)
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.a2, self.W2)
        yHat = self.sigmoid(self.z3) 
        return yHat

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        #Apply sigmoid activation function to scalar, vector, or matrix
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

    def sigmoidPrime(self,z):
        #Gradient of sigmoid
        return np.exp(-z)/((1+np.exp(-z))**2)

    def costFunction(self, X, y):
        #Compute cost for given X,y, use weights already stored in class.
        self.yHat = self.forward(X)
        J = 0.5*sum((y-self.yHat)**2)/X.shape[0] + (self.Lambda/2)*(sum(sum(self.W1**2)) + sum(self.W2**2))

        return J

    def costFunctionPrime(self, X, y):
        #Compute derivative with respect to W and W2 for a given X and y:
        self.yHat = self.forward(X)

        delta3 = np.multiply(-(y-self.yHat), self.sigmoidPrime(self.z3))
        dJdW2 = np.dot(self.a2.T, delta3)/X.shape[0] + self.Lambda*self.W2

        delta2 = np.dot(delta3, self.W2.T)*self.sigmoidPrime(self.z2)
        dJdW1 = np.dot(X.T, delta2)/X.shape[0] + self.Lambda*self.W1  

        return dJdW1, dJdW2

    #Helper Functions for interacting with other classes:
    def getParams(self):
        #Get W1 and W2 unrolled into vector:
        params = np.concatenate((self.W1.ravel(), self.W2.ravel()))
        return params

    def setParams(self, params):
        #Set W1 and W2 using single paramater vector.
        W1_start = 0
        W1_end = self.hiddenLayerSize * self.inputLayerSize
        self.W1 = np.reshape(params[W1_start:W1_end], (self.inputLayerSize , self.hiddenLayerSize))
        W2_end = W1_end + self.hiddenLayerSize*self.outputLayerSize
        self.W2 = np.reshape(params[W1_end:W2_end], (self.hiddenLayerSize, self.outputLayerSize))

    def computeGradients(self, X, y):
        dJdW1, dJdW2 = self.costFunctionPrime(X, y)
        return np.concatenate((dJdW1.ravel(), dJdW2.ravel()))

def computeNumericalGradient(N, X, y):
        paramsInitial = N.getParams()
        numgrad = np.zeros(paramsInitial.shape)
        perturb = np.zeros(paramsInitial.shape)
        e = 1e-4

        for p in range(len(paramsInitial)):
            #Set perturbation vector
            perturb[p] = e
            N.setParams(paramsInitial + perturb)
            loss2 = N.costFunction(X, y)

            N.setParams(paramsInitial - perturb)
            loss1 = N.costFunction(X, y)

            #Compute Numerical Gradient
            numgrad[p] = (loss2 - loss1)/(2*e)

            #Return the value we changed to zero:
            perturb[p] = 0

        #Return Params to original value:
        N.setParams(paramsInitial)

        return numgrad

class trainer(object):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N

    def callbackF(self, params):
        self.N.setParams(params)
        self.J.append(self.N.costFunction(self.X, self.y))
        self.testJ.append(self.N.costFunction(self.testX, self.testY))

    def costFunctionWrapper(self, params, X, y):
        self.N.setParams(params)
        cost = self.N.costFunction(X, y)
        grad = self.N.computeGradients(X, y)

        return cost, grad

    def train(self, trainX, trainY, testX, testY):
        self.X = trainX
        self.y = trainY
        self.testX = testX
        self.testY = testY

        self.J = []
        self.testJ = []

        params0 = self.N.getParams()

        options = {'maxiter': 1000, 'disp': True}
        _res = optimize.minimize(self.costFunctionWrapper, params0, jac = True, method = 'BFGS', args = (trainX, trainY), options = options, callback = self.callbackF)
        self.N.setParams(_res.x)
        self.optimizationResults = _res


trainX, testX, trainY, testY = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state=0)

NN = Neural_Network(Lambda = 0.0003)
numgrad = computeNumericalGradient(NN, X, y)
grad = NN.computeGradients(X,y)
print(np.linalg.norm(grad-numgrad)/np.linalg.norm(grad+numgrad))

T = trainer(NN)
T.train(X, y, testX, testY)

Actual_value = y*5
Predicted_value = NN.forward(X)*5

plot(Actual_value, Predicted_value, 'or')
ylim([0,5])
xlim([0,5])
grid(1)
show()


error = []
Diff = abs(Actual_value - Predicted_value)
for i in Diff:
    if i >= 0.5:
        error.append(i)

#print(Actual_value)
#print()
#print(Predicted_value)
print(max(Diff))        
#print(error)
print(len(error))
```

Comment: The core question here ("why does normalizing the variable(s) lead to different results") is on-topic at [stats.se], but not here.  If you want to ask a question about programming (ie, your specific implementation of the NN), you need to a) include the code in question here directly (and please not the _entire_ thing if it's rather large) and b) have a specific programming/implementation question.

Comment: I edited your title into something more specific to what you're wondering about - not sure if it's 100% correct though - feel free to edit it as required for it to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is because changing of error surface. Gradient moves in error surface. If you normalize input correctly then neural network quickly will rich to global minima. But if normalization makes error surface scaled, then neural network will go out of error surface and process will go slower. Some time even will not go at all.

[image]